# Where/what is the specification for odata.service meta tag?

Tags: metadata, odata

I would like to add some tags to our web app to enable auto-discovery of our odata feeds.

So for example Nerd Dinner has the following tag:

```
<link rel="odata.service" title="NerdDinner.com OData Service" href="/Services/OData.svc" /><link rel="odata.feed" title="NerdDinner.com OData Service - Dinners" href="/Services/OData.svc/Dinners" />
```

The trouble is that I have 4 different feeds and am unclear if I am allowed to add multiple `link rel="odata.service"` to the document.

Where is the specification for this meta tag?

(follow on question, are there any apps that take advantage of this tag that I can use to test out behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Pablo has a great description of this tag proposal to advertise OData support over on his blog at : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pablo/archive/2010/06/15/advertising-support-for-odata-in-web-pages.aspx  Mike has an entry on his blog about an IE extension which can read this header and popup a UI for the data service http://blog.flasko.net/post/3213799517/odata-extension-for-internet-explorer.
  Hope this helps